# Overlapped letters in QtCreator doc

Tags: qt-creator

I upgraded OS from Fedora Core 25 to FC26. After the upgrade, help system of Qt Creator does not shown correctly. Some part of documentation is overlapped and hard to read. Changing font style and font size does not help. Here is screenshot.

[image]

How I can correct it?